# Unable to create temporary file / permissions denied while running git in docker cloning to shared VirtualBox folder

Tags: git, docker, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have mounted an external SDD as a shared folder into a VirtualBox running Ubuntu. There is a script running in Docker which executes git clone at some point. When it runs it fails because it cannot create temp files which git needs.

The shared folder is explicitly mounted for my ubuntu user name. Script create a temp user in container with gid:1000 uid:1000 and operates under this name.

Comment: What are permissions on the shared folder?

Comment: 777, recursive. I have also changed owner to my user name - same result. 
The problem is not docker specific, I can reproduce it just by running git clone

Comment: What's the error with git clone?

Comment: fatal: Unable to create temporary file ‚….‘: Permission denied
fatal: index-pack failed

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the way how VirtualBox handles permissions on shared folder